# Блокировка кнопки input на странице

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как лучше сделать блокировку `submit` кнопок до того момента, пока вся страница не загрузится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите для кнопок disabled:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" disabled />
```

В DOM-ready разблокируйте

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Так не работает, после загрузки страницы кнопки не активируются.

Comment: А может вы где-то ошибку допустили или что-то еще влияет на работу скрипта? Вот, этот же пример в действии - [http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9UKjR/](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9UKjR/). Чтоб убедиться - закоментируйте разблокировку в JS

Comment: Код рабочий, jquery был версии ниже 1.6, поэтому не работало, сейчас обновил его до последней версии и всё заработало.